# Reference object property 'field1' using index from {#for}

Tags: javascript, jtemplates

Is it possible to refer to n object property in a jTemplate `{#if}` by dynamically creating the property name using the index from a `{#for}` loop?

Example:

```
{#for i = 1 to 5} 
    <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="textbox" id="thisbox_{$T.i}" value="{#if $T.log.field{$T.i} != null}...{#/if}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
{#/for}
```

How can I to refer to property `$T.log.field#` where `#` is the current index from the `{#for}`?
It obviously fails when it attempts to parse `{$T.log.field{$T.i}}` but I'm wondering how this can be written to work or if it's even possible.

Comment: I managed to fix this by referring to the property using reflection. When I changed my {#if} statement to this: {#if $T.log['field' + $T.i] != null}, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question:

I managed to fix this by referring to the property using reflection. I changed my {#if} statement to this:

```
{#if $T.log['field' + $T.i] != null} ... some code here {#/if}
```

Referring to the field by using ['field' + $T.i] worked as expected.